# Replacing multiple methods with single methods using functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a code with routines like this (the actual code base is pretty extensive but I am presenting a minimal version for explaining it)

```
class TestClass {
    void anotherRoutine2(){
      //some code logic
    }
    
    void someOtherRoutine2(){
      //some code logic
    }
    
    void method1() {
      routine1();
      anotherRoutine2();
      routine3();
    }

    void method2() {
      routine1();
      someOtherRoutine2();
      routine3();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestClass object1 = new TestClass();
      object1.method1();
      object1.method2();
    }
}
```

so we can see that the only way method1 and method2 differs is method1 is calling anotherRoutine2 whereas method2 is calling someOtherRoutine2.

I am trying to use functional programming in this scenario whereby I want to combine method1 and method2 in such a way that the routines which are changed is passed as argument. So I am planning to do the following

```
class TestClass {
    void anotherRoutine2(){
      //some code logic
    }
    
    void someOtherRoutine2(){
      //some code logic
    }

    void newMethod(Runnable methodName) {
      routine1();
      methodName.run();
      routine3();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestClass object1 = new TestClass();
      object1.method1(()->object1.anotherRoutine2());
      object1.method2(()->object1.someOtherRoutine2());
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few typos (should be `newMethod`) but you can do it that way.  Or use a method reference as follows:

```
TestClass object1 = new TestClass();
object1.newMethod(object1::anotherRoutine2);
object1.newMethod(object1::someOtherRoutine2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) sugest making a class that `implements runnable`.

```
class TestClass {
    class anotherRoutine2 implements runnable{
      void run(){
          //some code logic
      }
    }

    void someOtherRoutine2 implements runnable{
      void run(){
          //some code logic
      }
    }

     void newMethod(Runnable methodName) {
       routine1();
       methodName.run();
       routine3();
     }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestClass object1 = new TestClass();
      object1.newMethod(new object1.anotherRoutine2());
      object1.newMethod(new object1.someOtherRoutine2());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure if implementing Runnable is required as I don't intend it to be run by thread

Comment: The OP is simply using the Runnable interface as a way to call a method with no arguments and a void return.  It's no different than any other functional interface so it can be called with a lambda or method reference if the syntax permits.

Comment: But why even use run? why not just pass a void and call it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by passing a "void." How would you do that without using a lambda or method reference?  What argument type would you pass a method too?  Did you try it?

Comment: Fair enough. . .